# I want to check whether a primary key exists on sqlite table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite

I have an sqlite database on my Iphone app. That database has a table named "Students"
and It has 10 rows of data with keys from 1 to 11. But I want to test whether a primary key with value "3" exists on the table by objective c coding.

Comment: I assume you mean it has 10 rows with keys 1 to 11 but one key missing.

Answer (score 1):

Run the select query, if it returns no record then the record does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a select query on it.  The in depth info on how to do that is [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

The basic steps are:

- open the database
- prepare a select statement
- bind host values
- evaluate the prepared statement
- tidy up

The code looks something like this

```
// Database already opened
// All error checking omitted because I am lazy

sqlite3_stmt statement;
// Replace columns below with the names of your actual columns
// and key with the name of the primary key column
errorResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbConnection, 
                                 "select columns from students where key = ?",
                                 -1,
                                 &statement,
                                 NULL);
// error check and handle any
errorResult = sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, 3); // Put 3 in place of first question mark
// error check and handle any
while ((errorResult = sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    // Use sqlite3 column functions to get data 
    // http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html
}
// error check and handle any
errorCheck = sqlite3_finalize(statement);
// error check and handle any
```